# How to change color of element inside of div (css)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the color of an element inside a div.  As you can see, in the code below I have attempted to change the "i" class so that when the input-field is focused the side icon (from font-awesome) is highlighted in the color dodger blue.

```css
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: #696969;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ced4da;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.email-input-field,
.password-input-field {
  position: relative;
}

input:focus+i {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.email-input-field i {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: darkgrey;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.password-input-field i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  padding: 9px 12px;
  color: darkgrey;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 210px;
  height: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  width: 267px;
  height: 28px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #42BB97;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #3BA384;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div classs="login-form">
  <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="email-input-field">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <input type="email" name="emailPost" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="password-input-field">
        <i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <input type="password" name="passwordPost" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <div class="submit-button">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `<i>` elements come before your inputs and the `+` targets the sibling after the element in `input:focus+i`

Comment: @j08691 That's why I removed that comment. Refresh! Blame Cache! `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @j08691 [yes](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)!

Comment: @j08691Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` is a sibling selector that selects any element that's next to the current element. So when you are using it, it won't go to the previous element of `<i>`. You need to change your HTML structure, so that the `<i>` comes after the `<input>`.

```
<div class="email-input-field">
  <input type="email" name="emailPost" placeholder="Email" required>
  <i class = "fa fa-envelope fa-lg" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
</div>
<div class="password-input-field">
  <input type="password" name="passwordPost" placeholder="Password" required>
  <i class = "fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
</div>
```

I change the position of the `<i>` to come after the `<input>` and placed the cursor inside the password field and it works for me.

[image: preview]

Also, don't forget to give the following CSS.

```
.email-input-field i {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: darkgrey;
  transition: 0.3s;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

The `left` and `top` properties are missing.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. And thank you for the explanation! Great answer!

Comment: My pleasure! Thanks and you too! :)

Comment: @OmarDajani Yay! :)